# Azure Web App Bot - Cortana Invocation name exists

Tags: azure, bots, cortana

An old Azure Web App Bot with a Cortana binding has an invocation name I would like to use on my new Web App Bot. However, I received following error

> Skill with display name 'myawesomebot' already exists for this market. Trace
>   ID : 873xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxcxxxxxxx

Thus, I removed the old Web App Bot (deleted all resources), but still, this error message appears. Is there a time delay, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't delete the channel first, the channel connection will be orphaned when you delete the web app bot.  Send me a note at skillsup at microsoft dot com with the invocation phrase and I'll get it fixed.  We're working on a general fix (but I can't promise an ETA).

Comment: Yes, I didn't delete it... Email has been sent.